# How to add the emctype attribute in a backend form of Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I created a content plugin for the com_content component and I had added an input file control to allow the user uploading a pdf file in the backend.

Now I would like to add the attribute "enctype" with "multipart/form-data" as value into the form in the backend to enable the upload but I didn't find a method to do that. On the onContentPrepareForm event, there is a JForm parameter but there is no way to change the form's attributes.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no solution.

The only way I found to do that is to override the edit.php file in the article view of the com_content component in the template of the backend of Joomla but nothing with a content plugin.